# Updating a IMobileServiceSyncTable

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, azure-mobile-services

I am integrating Azure Easy Tables with my Xamarin.Forms application and thus far it is working. I can do GET and POST on my Azure table without any issues. However, how do I update an existing item in my local `MobileServiceSyncTable` and push this to the cloud?

I have for testing purposes created a simple `Model` named `Person` which has a few standard properties like `FirstName` and so on. Now, what I want to do is, quite simply, update a persons `FirstName` property. So far, this is my - obviously failed - attempt:

```
public async Task PatchPerson(string id)
{
    await Initialize();

    var person = personTable.Where(p => p.Id == id);

    person.Firstname = 'Something else';

    await personTable.UpdateAsync(person); // error here

    await SyncPeople();
 }
```

IntelliSense informs me of an error when trying to pass this `var` to `UpdateAsync()`:

> Cannot convert from 'Microsoft.WindowsAzure.MobileServices.IMobileServiceTableQuery' to 'Models.Person'>

Fine. So I cast the object like so, which removes the error:

```
public async Task PatchPerson(string id)
{
   await Initialize();

   var person = (Person)personTable.Where(p => p.Id == id); //cast

   person.Firstname = "Something else";

   await personTable.UpdateAsync(person); // no error here

   await SyncPeople();
}
```

Now when I compile and run this code, the program crashes with the following error message:

> [0:] Error adding person. Error message: Specified cast is not valid.

What am I doing wrong, and how do I do it right?

Comment: `.Where` can return multiple results. It can't be case to a `Person` object unless you specify logic to only take the first one or something similar.

Comment: @dvo Hm, ok - thanks. I'll try work that in and see how it goes.

Comment: I am not a xamarin developer, but LINQ also has a `.Find( )` method that you could use instead of `.Where( )` and it _should_ return the first occurrence of the person with that ID. This is good when you are querying for unique keys (like ID). You should still be able to use `p => p.Id == id`

Comment: @dvo Looks like `.Find()` is not part of the `IMobileServiceSyncTable<T>` API:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.windowsazure.mobileservices.sync.imobileservicesynctable?view=azure-dotnet

Comment: Looks like it's getting above my pay-grade lol. Try to pull the first element of the table. There are properties for `.query` or methods like `.ToListAsync()` that may be able to get one step closer. Then try to pull an index `[0]` or `.First()` if available. Basically, try to get one element instead of a list of elements. Then you can cast properly. Sorry for my lack of knowledge.

Comment: @dvo Haha :-) Thanks for the inputs, I'll try them out in an effort to get closer to a proper solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so I found a way to get around it.

I implemented a new method

```
public async Task<Person> GetPerson(string id)
{
    await Initialize();

    return await personTable.LookupAsync(id);
}
```

And then updated my `PatchPerson()` method like so:

```
public async Task PatchPerson(string id)
{
    await Initialize();

    var person = await GetPerson(id);

    person.Age += 1;

    await personTable.UpdateAsync(person);

    await SyncPeople();
}
```

From a `ViewModel` I can now return this `Person` object from my Azure Easy Table:

```
var person = await azureMobileService.GetPerson("C3EC52BE-6FAF-490C-A78F-7AB50F796311");
```

And then I can pass this object to my new `PatchPerson()` method:

```
await azureMobileService.PatchPerson(person.Id);
```

This successfully updates the proper `Person` object in my Azure backend, and the changes are reflected in my app.